# Check if value is in diapason disassembly

Tags: c, comparison, compiler-optimization, disassembly

I am using RH850 controler and compiler greenHills in C language. In range check like this:

```
if ((x>=2) && (x<=5))
    y=1
```

It is compiled with Osize option. When it is compiled it seemed like this:

```
zxb r7
addi -2,r7,r1
cmp 3,r1
bnh .L1295
```

`.L1295` is the label of `y=1` (This `y=1` is used for other changes, on some other conditions too). Both instructions affected same flags.

The check `(x>=2)` is realized with this code: `addi -2,r7,r1`. But flag result of this instruction, will be cleaned by next one and there is incorrect. At least I think so.

Obviously I am wrong. Can someone explain this disassembler fragment?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is transforming the check as follows:

```
  x >= 2 && x <= 5
= (x - 2) >= (2 - 2) && (x - 2) <= (5 - 2)
= (x - 2) >= 0 && (x - 2) <= 3
```

The code compares `r1`, which is `x - 2`, to `3` and "branches if not higher" meaning `r1` in `0, 1, 2, or 3` (or `x` in `2, 3, 4, or 5`) will branch to set `y = 1`.

Comment: My question is not the logic. It is for flags. I thought that "addi"  will set some flags, But "cmp" will change them again. And I though that flags from "addi" will be lost.

Comment: They are lost, but you only need the results from `cmp`.